# SQLdatasource select put into text box

Tags: c#, sql, textbox, sqldatasource

I am trying to populate a text box from a sqldarasource but I keep getting "Object reference not set to instance of an object". Anyone have a clue what im doing wrong? My select statement that I've configured works fine. Here is the code I'm using.

```
FNTextbox.Text = sqlmedia.SelectParameters["CFN"].ToString();
```

sqlmedia is a sqldatasource that grabs data from a stored procedure simple statement. i created this using the visual studio toolbox. I do initialize earlier in my pageload.

Comment: Please provide little more context as to what is sqlmedia, how is it initialized etc, in order to undeerstand the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you havent instantiated sqlmedia. In your code somewhere you have to create an instance of this class e.g.

```
sqlmedia = new SqlDataSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the "CFN" parameter first:

sqlmedia.SelectParameters.Item("CFN").DefaultValue = value;